# Ran out of messages before reaching ending offset <offset_value> for topic X

Tags: spark-streaming

java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Ran out of messages before reaching ending offset  for topic  partition  start 24382671. This should not happen, and indicates that messages may have been lost.

I am getting above issue while consuming bunch data from topic using spark streaming.Is there upper limit at spark end and is it configurable.

Answer (score 0):

1. That means maybe something is wrong with Kafka, check your Kafka log first.
2. Accommodate `fetch.message.max.bytes` in your kafkaParams to match your data scale.